# Probability of Breakdowns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, poisson-distribution

Hi Math Stack Exchange Community,

I am stuck with this question and not sure how can I solve it. Any help would be much appreciated.

> You work as part of the maintenance team in a manufacturing company and
> keep a record of the machine breakdowns. From your past​ experience, it
> seems that there are on average 2.5 serious breakdowns every year in your
> company.​ Then,
>
> a) The probability that there will be 5 breakdowns in a given year is?
>
> b) The probability that there will be fewer than 4 breakdowns in a given year is?
>
> c) The probability that there will be at least 2 breakdowns in a given year is?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Any idea on what distribution might be relevant?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. This is not a "do this for me" site. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'd recommend taking the advice given to you on your previous questions and improve your question quality, as specified [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: As a hint, you correctly tagged this problem with the tag [Poisson Distribution].  Now... remind yourself and us why this is the correct label for the problem.  What do you know about poisson distributions?

Comment: Poisson distribution is e^(-lambda)*(lambda^k/k!). I know that we should use poisson distribution but I am not sure how to implement it to this question. Any help would be appreciated. @JMoravitz

Comment: It is already a well edited question. Instead of talking about the layout of the question, comments regarding the question itself would be much more helpful for me though @EthanBolker

Comment: The responses to our leading questions about "*What is the poisson distribution*" and "*What does $\lambda$ represent in a poisson distribution*" and "*What do you think $\lambda$ should be here for your specific problem*" should have been included in the original post before our ever having had to ask the questions rather than including them in the comments only after we asked.  That is what @ EthanBolker was referring to.

Comment: λ, x, y, z or whatever it is just a variable in the formula @JMoravitz Are you guys willing to help instead of trying to scold me about the way I ask my question??

Comment: So then... as alluded to earlier, the next leading question in the sequence to understanding this problem is "*What does $\lambda$ represent in a poisson distribution?*"  This is then followed by "*What do you think $\lambda$ should be here for your specific problem?*"  Both of these questions should be easily answerable if you have the [definition of a poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) available to you.  It is not "*just a variable*", it has very specific meaning.

Comment: I actually don't really know what that is. I would appreciate if you could explain that too. @JMoravitz

Comment: On Wikipedia it says it is the expected number of occurrences. @JMoravitz

Comment: Quoted from the linked wikipedia article: "*The positive real number $\lambda$ is equal to the expected value of $X$ and also to its variance.*"  In your problem, the relevant sentence is "*it seems that there are on average 2.5 serious breakdowns every year in your company.*"  The words "average" and "expected value" are interchangable in this context.  The problem's wording implies it follows a poisson distribution and then with that sentence tells you that $\lambda = 2.5$.

Comment: So, then, the only thing left to consider then is for each of the parts to the problem, decide what $k$ is or what values of $k$ there are to add together the results, noting that for instance $\Pr(X\leq 2) = \Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)$ and similar and the formula you cite for poisson distributions was phrased for equals signs, not for less-than-or-equals signs.

Comment: So according to λ=2.5, the first question should be like, e^(-2.5)*(2.5)^5/5! Am I right?

Comment: Yes.$~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Okay then, how can I implement the sub questions b) and c)? They look way trickier. What do you think about them? @JMoravitz

Comment: Quoted from my comment above: "*noting that for instance $\Pr(X\leq 2) = \Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)$ and similar...*"

Comment: Okay for the sub question b) this can be applied. But how can I implement this for the last sub question though? @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting comments:

A random variable which follows a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) takes non-negative integer values and satisfies:

$$\Pr(X=k) = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$$

where $\lambda$ is the expected value of $X$ and $k$ is the actual number of occurrences we see in the timeframe.

The problem statement here tells us that the average number of breakdowns per year is $2.5$... in other words it tells us that $\lambda = 2.5$ here.

The first problem asks us what the probability is that we see $5$ breakdowns.  That is, it asks us for $\Pr(X=5)$ given that $\lambda = 2.5$.  That is, as you correctly found in the comments after coaxing:

$$\Pr(X=5)=\dfrac{e^{-2.5}(2.5)^5}{5!}$$

For the second problem, it asks us the probability is we see *fewer* than $4$ breakdowns.  That is to say, that we saw $0,1,2$ or $3$ breakdowns.  We note that $\Pr(X< 4) = \Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\Pr(X=3)$, use the values of $0,1,2,3$ in place of $k$ for each of the respective calculations, all still using the lambda value of $\lambda = 2.5$, and conclude.

For the final problem, it asks us the probability that we see *at least* $2$ breakdowns.  That is to say, that we saw $2,3,4,5,6,7,\dots$ number of breakdowns.  In other words, that we did not see $0,$ or $1$ breakdowns.

That would be $\Pr(X\geq 2) = \Pr(X=2)+\Pr(X=3)+\Pr(X=4)+\dots$, or more easily calculatable it would be $\Pr(X\geq 2) = 1 - \Pr(X<2) = 1 - \Pr(X=0)-\Pr(X=1)$.  That is to say, some times it is easier to calculate the probability of the *opposite* event and subtract away from $1$.

---

Note: Here, we were given $\lambda$ in terms of average number of breakdowns *per year* and we were asked questions about the number of breakdowns we actually see *in a year*... we used the same timeframe for both the given information of $\lambda$ as well as for the questions we were asking.  This is important to note.  You might in future problems need to rephrase things to get them to match.  If for instance, we were asked the probability that we get $5$ breakdowns in a *decade* (*a span of ten years*) for instance, then $2.5$ being the number of breakdowns in year wouldn't work for our lambda, but it would instead become $\lambda = 25$ as that would be the average number of breakdowns in a *decade*.  We needed to make sure the timeframes we were referring to matched.

Comment: "it would be Pr(X≥2)=1−Pr(X<2)=1−Pr(X=0)'+'Pr(X=1)" Did you mean '+' here 1−Pr(X=0)'+'Pr(X=1)? @JMoravitz

Comment: $\Pr(X\geq 2) = 1 - \Pr(X<2) = 1 - \left(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)\right) = 1 - \Pr(X=0)-\Pr(X=1)$

Comment: Oh okay sorry about that @JMoravitz

Comment: Getting at least $2$ is equivalent to *not* getting zero *and not* getting $1$

Comment: So the last one would be like, 1-((e^(-2.5)*(2.5)^0/0!)+(e^(-2.5)*(2.5)^1/1!)) Am I right? @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz This is a nicely written detailed correct answer. You spent a lot of time here and in comments teaching the OP things he probably should have learned (or at least tried to learn) in a course or by reading. I hope he does not expect this kind of handholding on all his questions ...

Comment: Do you except every single person to know everything about math or something? If that would be the case we wouldn't need these kind of Q&A platforms to ask questions. I am trying to learn and that's why I am here. I hope you can show some respect to that @EthanBolker

Comment: I really appreciate this comprehensive answer, thank you, helped a lot :) @JMoravitz

Comment: @smith.john1919 I respect the people who ask here when they have done their best to answer their question before asking, None of your postings does this. (No further responses from me.(

Comment: You can't now the amount of effort I put in this question. I didn't prefer to put the data that I obtained throughout my struggle because I wanted to get to the point for the people to help me in a better way. If I would shared the data with them it would not help them instead it would make things more complicated and worse. Instead of arguing try to be helpful to people to make this community a better place (at least try). @EthanBolker

Comment: @smith for what it's worth, I and many other users agree with Ethan's point of view here. While you might not see the value in including your attempt, it greatly helps the answerer be able to pinpoint the exact part of the process where your understanding is flawed or even just say "yes, that's right" if it isn't flawed at all, allowing us to better tailor the help we give to be more effective and to the point.

Comment: Even if he is right the bitter in his speech is the controversial part. But anyway I won't type any other comments about this nonsense. Thanks for the answer again by the way @JMoravitz